# Android MapView: custom animation possible?

Tags: android, animation, android-mapview

Is it possible in Android to animate between two points in a Google MapView in a predefined number of seconds?

I want to write some sort of game where an object is flying from the start point to the end point. But the Object will be centered on the screen and the map shall be moved.

Do you have any idea how to do this? :)

Best,
kiwaque

Answer (score 0):

Call `animateTo()` on your [`MapController`](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapController.html).

Comment: Using animateTo() does not allow me to define a time range i think.

Comment: @kiwaque: Nothing allows you to define a time range. Hence, if you want a time range, you use `animateTo()` in chunks and introduce your own delays between chunks, or something.